# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException , HOW CAN i RESOLVE

Tags: java

```
public class Prog1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("WebDriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Users\\sh\\workspace\\Java2020\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

 driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

System.out.println("Hello world");
```

Comment: Are you using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this line; don't use upper case `"Webdriver.chrome.driver"`

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/drivders/chromedriver.exe");
```

And also change this `driver1` to use `driver`

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Time out exception driver object should be driver instead of driver1

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException